# ffmpeg cannot detect file while os can

Tags: python, windows, file, python-2.7, ffmpeg

### Issue

I'm trying to load images in a sub-directory with files named:

- .\images\image0.png
- .\images\image1.png
- .\images\image2.png
- .\images\image3.png
- ... etc ...
- .\images\image8.png
- .\images\image9.png

When I run code:

```
 print os.path.exists('.\\images\\image0.png')
 cmd = "ffmpeg -f image2 -r 20 -i .\\images\\image%01d.png -c:v libx264 -r 20 .\\images\\output.mp4"
 os.system(cmd)
```

it results in:

```
 True
 //blah blah blah ffmpeg start up stuff blah blah blah 

 [image2 @ 00000000026ceda0] Could find no file with with path '.\images\image%01
 d.png' and index in the range 0-4
 .\images\image%01d.png: No such file or directory
```

I even checked:

```
 os.getcwd()
```

Was the right path.

Could someone shed some light on my issue?
I'm pretty sure my ffmpeg command is correct (it has worked for me in the past). I'm wondering if there might be a reason that ffmpeg won't recognize my current working directory? (And won't take that relative path as a result?)

Thanks! Advice/suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How about actually running the same ffmpeg command in the same DOS prompt session you run the Python script from and being 100% sure that it works instead of just "pretty sure"?

Comment: And you can also rule out the relative path issue by just calling `os.path.abspath('.\\images')` and using that in place of `'.\\images'` in your `cmd` string.

Comment: Thats what I meant by pretty sure. It just doesn't work in THIS context. And I'll try that.

Comment: Another way to rule out the relative path issue is to run `echo %cd% && ffmpeg …` instead of just `ffmpeg`, which will make it print out the current working directory that `ffmpeg` will see.

Comment: @abarnert My path is incorrect - it doesn't use my cwd. It routes to my documents folder. I think the cause of that is because I edited my registry for my command prompt to auto open to my documents. Apprently, this effects how os.system calls commands. By any chance, would you know how to set my cmd to open in a specific directory without this effect? (Btw. thanks for your help! If you post this as your answer, I'd gladly accept.)

Comment: Unrelated to your issue: since your input is probably RGB, and you're using libx264 consider adding `-pix_fmt yuv420p` as an output option. Otherwise the output will likely have an incompatible pixel format for "dumb" players.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard. Is there a similar issue with openCV? I've noticed that videos I've rendered using this and openCV videowriter can only be played by vlc.

Comment: I'm not sure. The console output of ffmpeg will confirm the pixel format for the video in question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you've set up your system so every new `cmd.exe` shell immediately cd's to your Documents directory, so `ffmpeg` is trying to run there.

The obvious way around that is to just give `ffmpeg` absolute paths instead of relative:

```
images = os.path.abspath('.\\images')
cmd = "ffmpeg -f image2 -r 20 -i {}\\image%01d.png -c:v libx264 -r 20 {}\\output.mp4".format(images, images)
```

Alternatively, you can always stick a `cd` command into what you send to the `system` function:

```
curpath = os.path.abspath(os.getcwd())
cmd = "cd {} && ffmpeg -f image2 -r 20 -i .\\images\\image%01d.png -c:v libx264 -r 20 .\\images\\output.mp4".format(curpath)
```

However, the best solution is to stop using `system` entirely, as the documentation for `system` suggests, and leave the shell out of it:

```
cmd = "ffmpeg -f image2 -r 20 -i .\\images\\image%01d.png -c:v libx264 -r 20 .\\images\\output.mp4"
subprocess.check_call(cmd)
```

(Someone is invariably going to suggest in a comment that you can't use a string with `subprocess` unless `shell=True`. That's true on Unix, but not on Windows. In fact, on Windows, if you pass a list of parameters, `subprocess` will just join them up into a string to pass to `CreateProcess`. If you don't know how to escape your parameters properly for Windows, a list can still be a good idea—but if you've got a perfectly good command line, just use it.)

Comment: Thanks again for your help. I'll visit the documentation for both os.system and subprocess. I'll accept in a few. I've also gotten around my issue - created a .bat file with cmd.exe \c \start path. Running that .bat file will open cmd.exe in my path without tinkering with regedit